# I'm getting an X509 error with Amazon AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Just wondering if anyone knows why Amazon's AWS would be telling me "The X509 Certificate you provided does not exist in our records."

Here's the code I'm using...

```
$sqs = new AmazonSQS();
$queue_url = 'my_url';
$options = array(
    'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 10,
);
$resp = $sqs->receive_message($queue_url, $options);

print_r($resp);
```

Here's the response I get...

```
[Type] => Sender
[Code] => InvalidClientTokenId
[Message] => The X509 Certificate you provided does not exist in our records.
[Detail] => CFSimpleXML Object
```

Here's the CFCredentials array I'm using inside config.inc.php...

```
'@default' => array(
    'key' => 'my-key',
    'secret' => 'my-secret',
    'default_cache_config' => 'cache',
    'certificate_authority' => FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting this error was because I am using MAMP PRO which doesn't have CURL installed with SSL.  Only CURL.

So to get around this so I could test from my local machine was the below code.  Note the "@" on the second line.  I used this to suppress the warning that is given out by disable_ssl() method.

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
@$s3->disable_ssl();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Amazon SQS, you have to specifically sign up for Amazon SQS ; it looks like you are not sign-up. You can do it by visiting [this page](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) and clicking the button labeled "Sign up for Amazon SQS".

Comment: I actually am signed up and have created multiple queues already.

Comment: Do you have to be using 'https' ?